# calculus and functional equation

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function
of the form 
$$
f(x)=\cos(p(x)),
$$
where $p:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ satisfies the relation
$$
p(x+y)\equiv p(x)+p(y) \,\, ({\rm mod} \,\, 2\pi).
$$
How to show that $f(x)=\cos(ax)$ for some $a\in \Bbb R$ ?.

Comment: To verify that $p(x)$ is a linear function of the form that you desire, I think it suffices to check that $p(\alpha \cdot x) \equiv \alpha \cdot  p(x) \pmod{2\pi}$ for each $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. I think this is obvious for rational $\alpha$, and it follows for irrational $\alpha$ by the (presumed) continuity of $p(x)$.

Comment: Thank you!  It is a problem how to drive some regularity of p from the continuity of f?